# Android resource linking failed and error: failed processing manifest

Tags: java, android

I get this error when I try to make the app aab. Apk gives no problem but aab gives such an error. Could you help?

```
error: failed processing manifest.
```

The option 'android.enableAapt2' is deprecated and should not be used anymore.

```
Android resource linking failed
    Output:  C:\Users\sezer\Desktop\videosikistirma\app\build\intermediates\merged_manÄ±fests\release\processReleaseManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml:21: error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher (aka video.compress.optimizasyon:mipmap/ic_launcher) not found.
    C:\Users\sezer\Desktop\videosikistirma\app\build\intermediates\merged_manÄ±fests\release\processReleaseManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml:21: error: resource string/app_name (aka video.compress.optimizasyon:string/app_name) not found.
    C:\Users\sezer\Desktop\videosikistirma\app\build\intermediates\merged_manÄ±fests\release\processReleaseManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml:21: error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher_round (aka video.compress.optimizasyon:mipmap/ic_launcher_round) not found.
    C:\Users\sezer\Desktop\videosikistirma\app\build\intermediates\merged_manÄ±fests\release\processReleaseManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml:21: error: resource style/AppTheme (aka video.compress.optimizasyon:style/AppTheme) not found.
    C:\Users\sezer\Desktop\videosikistirma\app\build\intermediates\merged_manÄ±fests\release\processReleaseManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml:32: error: resource style/AppTheme.NoActionBar (aka video.compress.optimizasyon:style/AppTheme.NoActionBar) not found.
    C:\Users\sezer\Desktop\videosikistirma\app\build\intermediates\merged_manÄ±fests\release\processReleaseManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml:67: error: resource string/title_activity_main2 (aka video.compress.optimizasyon:string/title_activity_main2) not found.
    C:\Users\sezer\Desktop\videosikistirma\app\build\intermediates\merged_manÄ±fests\release\processReleaseManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml:77: error: resource string/app_name (aka video.compress.optimizasyon:string/app_name) not found.
    C:\Users\sezer\Desktop\videosikistirma\app\build\intermediates\merged_manÄ±fests\release\processReleaseManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml:77: error: resource style/FilePickerTheme (aka video.compress.optimizasyon:style/FilePickerTheme) not found.
    C:\Users\sezer\Desktop\videosikistirma\app\build\intermediates\merged_manÄ±fests\release\processReleaseManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml:87: error: resource string/app_name (aka video.compress.optimizasyon:string/app_name) not found.
    C:\Users\sezer\Desktop\videosikistirma\app\build\intermediates\merged_manÄ±fests\release\processReleaseManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml:90: error: resource string/settings (aka video.compress.optimizasyon:string/settings) not found.
    C:\Users\sezer\Desktop\videosikistirma\app\build\intermediates\merged_manÄ±fests\release\processReleaseManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml:90: error: resource style/AppTheme.NoActionBar (aka video.compress.optimizasyon:style/AppTheme.NoActionBar) not found.
    C:\Users\sezer\Desktop\videosikistirma\app\build\intermediates\merged_manÄ±fests\release\processReleaseManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml:100: error: resource xml/file_provider_paths (aka video.compress.optimizasyon:xml/file_provider_paths) not found.
    C:\Users\sezer\Desktop\videosikistirma\app\build\intermediates\merged_manÄ±fests\release\processReleaseManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml:109: error: resource xml/nnf_provider_paths (aka video.compress.optimizasyon:xml/nnf_provider_paths) not found.
    C:\Users\sezer\Desktop\videosikistirma\app\build\intermediates\merged_manÄ±fests\release\processReleaseManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml:123: error: resource style/EasyPermissions.Transparent (aka video.compress.optimizasyon:style/EasyPermissions.Transparent) not found.
    C:\Users\sezer\Desktop\videosikistirma\app\build\intermediates\merged_manÄ±fests\release\processReleaseManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml:216: error: resource integer/google_play_services_version (aka video.compress.optimizasyon:integer/google_play_services_version) not found.
    error: failed processing manifest.
    
    Command: C:\Users\sezer\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows.jar\5e92c711566847d7e971f4759337ad82\aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link --proto-format\
            -I\
            C:\Users\sezer\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar\
            --manifest\
            C:\Users\sezer\Desktop\videosikistirma\app\build\intermediates\merged_manıfests\release\processReleaseManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
            -o\
            C:\Users\sezer\Desktop\videosikistirma\app\build\intermediates\lınked_res_for_bundle\release\bundleReleaseResources\bundled-res.ap_\
            --auto-add-overlay\
            -0\
            apk\
            --no-version-vectors
    Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows Daemon #0
```

Comment: Try "invalide cache and restart".

Comment: I tried but it still gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your /android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml :

`<string name="app_name">Your App Name here.</string>`